# Array json split elements to colums postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have this column **extra** which is **JSONB** from table called **subscribers** and the value for a given subscriber is :

```
{
  "valid": "N",
  "msisdn": "23490272",
  "account_info": [
    {
      "account_id": 110000616,
      "account_cur": "NGN",
      "account_type": "C",
      "account_class": "ww"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 110000617,
      "account_cur": "NGN",
      "account_type": "S",
      "account_class": "GHCXLA"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 110000618,
      "account_cur": "EUR",
      "account_type": "S",
      "account_class": "ww"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 110000619,
      "account_cur": "USD",
      "account_type": "C",
      "account_class": "ww"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 110000620,
      "account_cur": "SAR",
      "account_type": "Y",
      "account_class": "ww"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 110000621,
      "account_cur": "NGN",
      "account_type": "Y",
      "account_class": "ww"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 110000622,
      "account_cur": "NGN",
      "account_type": "S",
      "account_class": "ww"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 110000623,
      "account_cur": "NGN",
      "account_type": "S",
      "account_class": "ww"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 110000624,
      "account_cur": "NGN",
      "account_type": "S",
      "account_class": "ww"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 110000625,
      "account_cur": "NGN",
      "account_type": "S",
      "account_class": "ww"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 110000626,
      "account_cur": "NGN",
      "account_type": "S",
      "account_class": "ww"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 110000627,
      "account_cur": "NGN",
      "account_type": "S",
      "account_class": "ww"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 110000628,
      "account_cur": "NGN",
      "account_type": "S",
      "account_class": "ww"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 110000629,
      "account_cur": "NGN",
      "account_type": "S",
      "account_class": "ww"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 110000630,
      "account_cur": "NGN",
      "account_type": "S",
      "account_class": "ww"
    }
  ],
  "preapprovalId": "1517299109619",
  "reservedAmount": 0.0,
  "preapprovalStatus": "APPROVED"
}
```

I want to make the elements from the account_info into columns.I have tried this :

```
select extra #>'{account_info,0}'->>'account_id' Account,extra #>'{account_info,0}'->>'account_cur' Currency,extra #>'{account_info,0}'->>'account_type' Account_Type from subscribers s2 where id = 319;
  account  | currency | account_type
-----------+----------+--------------
 110000616 | NGN      | C
```

How can i have all the elements?

Comment: Do you want each array element as a row in your output? Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the expected output based on your sample data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I followed you correctly, you can use `jsonb_array_elements()` and a lateral join to unnest each array element to a separate row:

```
select 
    x.acc ->> 'account_id' account,
    x.acc ->> 'account_cur' currency,
    x.acc ->> 'account_type' account_type
from subscribers s
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(s.extra -> 'account_info') as x(acc)
where s.id = 319
```

Comment: GMB thank you that solved my problem. :) !!!!! I wasn't that familiar with lateral joins .